# Matplotlib x-axis limited range

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I've been trying to plot some data. The x-axis is limited to two years. My question is pretty simple can someones explain why X-axis is limited to date range from 2015Q1 - 2017Q1, when the available data is between 2015Q1 - 2020Q1. Is there something missing or incorrect with my code?

dd2

```
qtr     median  count
0   2015Q1  1290000.0   27
1   2015Q2  1330000.0   43
2   2015Q3  1570000.0   21
3   2015Q4  1371000.0   20
4   2016Q1  1386500.0   20
5   2016Q2  1767500.0   22
6   2016Q3  1427500.0   32
7   2016Q4  1501000.0   31
8   2017Q1  1700000.0   29
9   2017Q2  1630000.0   15
10  2017Q3  1687500.0   24
11  2017Q4  1450000.0   15
12  2018Q1  1505000.0   13
13  2018Q2  1494000.0   14
14  2018Q3  1415000.0   21
15  2018Q4  1150000.0   15
16  2019Q1  1228000.0   15
17  2019Q2  1352500.0   12
18  2019Q3  1237500.0   12
19  2019Q4  1455000.0   26
20  2020Q1  1468000.0   9
```

code

```
x = dd2['qtr']


y1 = dd2['count']
y2 = dd2['median']



fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,10))

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax2 = ax.twinx()


y1_plot = y1.plot(ax=ax2, color='green', legend=True, marker='*', label="median")
y2_plot = y2.plot(ax=ax, color='red',   legend=True, linestyle='--', marker='x', label="count")


plt.title('Price trend analysis')
ax.set_xticklabels(x, rotation='vertical',color='k', size=20)

ax.set_xlabel('year')
ax.set_ylabel('sold price')
ax2.set_ylabel('number of sales')

y1_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='median sold price')
y2_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='count')
plt.legend(handles=[y2_patch,y1_patch],loc='upper right')


plt.savefig('chart.png', dpi=300,bbox_inches ='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using mtick to plot all x-axis data.

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.IndexLocator(base=1, offset=0))
```

Comment: Glad to see you solved your problem. Can you please only highlight the part of the code necessary to implement the solution? This will make it easier for others to find the answer.

Comment: A better solution would be to plot your x and y data together, so pyplot can figure out where the xticks are supposed to go: `ax.plot(x, y1)` and `ax1.plot(x, y2)`.

Comment: @Junuxx thank you for suggesting a better solution, I'm new to python and pandas. Can you please be more specific of where to modify my code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through Pandas' Series plotting methods, I'd use pyplot to plot your x and y data together, like this:

```
# everything is the same up to 'ax2 = ax.twinx()'

# plot on your axes, save a reference to the line
line1 = ax.plot(x, y1, color="green", label="median sold price", marker='*')
line2 = ax2.plot(x, y2, color="red", label="count", marker='x')

# no need for messing with patches
lines = line1 + line2
labels = [l.get_label() for l in lines]
ax.legend(lines, labels, loc='upper right')

# this is the same as before again
plt.title('Price trend analysis')
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=90, color='k', size
ax.set_xlabel('year')
ax.set_ylabel('sold price')
ax2.set_ylabel('number of sales')

plt.savefig('chart.png', dpi=300,bbox_inches ='tight')
plt.show()
```

Comment: When I used the above code to plot the chart, the x-axis is limited 2018Q1 - 2019Q2 instead of 2015Q1 - 2020Q1.

Comment: @karweng: Right, whoops, that wasn't what I intended to do at all. Included the x arguments like I described.